# A group subset whose size divides order of the subgroup generated by it

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $d$ a divisor of $|G|$. Is there a subset $A$ of $G$ with $|A|=d$ such that $d$ divides order of the subgroup generated by $A$ ($|A|$ divides $|\langle A\rangle|$)?

Note that it is true if $G$ is generated by two elements, and also holds for all abelian (and CLT) groups.

Comment: Yes I think this is fairly easy. In fact you do it with $|A| \le \log_2 d$. For each prime power divisor $p^k$ of $d$ choose at most $k$ elements that generate a subgroup of order $p^k$ and then just take the union of these sets. You can add extra elements to $A$ to give the required size.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.